# How to allow @throws for case classes in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have legacy Scala code to upgrade from `2.13.3` version to `2.13.8` version. During the upgrade, I am facing the following error:

```
On line 2: error: `@throws` only allowed for methods and constructors
```

The error is occurring due to `@throws` not allowed for `case class`. The code is as follows:

```
scala> @throws[IllegalArgumentException]
     | final case class MyClass(name: String, age: Int)
       final case class MyClass(name: String, age: Int)
                        ^
On line 2: error: `@throws` only allowed for methods and constructors
```

Hence, how can I allow `@throws` for `case class` in Scala 2.13.8.

Comment: A case class that throw an exception during construction is probably one of the most unidiomatic things I have seen.

Comment: The idiomatic way would be to have a "smart constructor" in the companion object that returns an `Option` or a `Try` so that it can fail that way if the parameters don't make sense. You can then make the real constructor private.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work in my 2.13 REPL:

```scala
scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.15).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> final case class MyClass @throws(classOf[IllegalArgumentException]) (name: String, age: Int)
class MyClass
```

---

For anyone else that's curious, this behavior seems to have changed in 2.13.5: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/9465